# WebExtensions - How to paste text from clipboard to variable?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, firefox-addon-webextensions

I try to develop my extension for Firefox using WebExtensions and official tutorials.

And here is my problem: I tried to paste text from clipboard to variable but nothing is happening.
I modified a little this code from official site: [Reading from the clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Reading_from_the_clipboard)

Is it even possible? Can I paste code like this?

Here how my code looks like:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "description": "Paste from clipboard to variable test.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Clipboard test",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
         "page": "background-page.html"
    },

    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/clipboard-48.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "clipboardRead"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/clipboard-16.png",
            "32": "icons/clipboard-32.png"
        }
    }
}
```

**background-page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>background-page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
function paste() {
    var pasteText = document.querySelector("#output");
    pasteText.focus();
    document.execCommand("paste");
    console.log("pasteText.textContent: " + pasteText.textContent);
}

function toolbarButtonClick(){
    paste();
    console.log("Button clicked.");
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(toolbarButtonClick);
```

Comment: Define "nothing is happening". What do you expect to happen? Presumably, some output in the console. _Which console are you looking at?_

Comment: @Xan **>Define "nothing is happening".**
When I click the button function toolbarButtonClick() is called. In console appears "Button clicked." 
Than function paste() is called - text "pasteText.textContent: " appears. 
And nothing more. 

**What do you expect to happen?**

I expect after "pasteText.textContent: " console show me text from clipboart. 

**>Which console are you looking at?**

 Browser console not www console.
Thanks for your response.